# How to attach a file on Windows PC using Selenium WebDriver in Java

Tags: selenium

Manual steps:

1. Click Browse on the application Windows dialog box displays.
2. Enter file path in the file name field in windows dialog box.
3. Click the Open button
4. It attaches the file.

Code using the robot class:

```
@Test
public void test(){

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("attach"));
    
    element.click();
    
    waitSeconds(9000);
    

     Robot robot = new Robot();
    
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
    
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
    
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);
    
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
    
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);}
```

When I run the test, it works just fine except for the last line.
Last line presses enter key just fine. After that, dialog box opens again. So file is never attached. Windows dialog box has two buttons: open and cancel. It should press Open button once after the file path is entered in the file name field. How can I do it?

Comment: Try to simulate pressing Alt+O instead of Enter. Or insert the file path using `element.sendKeys("C:\...\D1.txt");` avoiding the upload dialog. See https://www.guru99.com/upload-download-file-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: UI field is not a text field. So cant insert the filepath in UI directly. I will try Alt+O

Comment: Check my answer. Better than using Robot I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Using `org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor` to set elements attribute 'value':

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor

//...

JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String script = "document.getElementsByClassName('attach')[0].setAttribute('value', 'C:\...\D1.txt');";
javascriptExecutor.executeScript(script);
```